# How should the files of a Flatpak application be removed?

Tags: flatpak

I installed an application using a command of the following form:

```
flatpak --user install -y --app --bundle "$DIR/Suphead.flatpak"
```

I uninstalled it using a command of the following form:

```
flatpak --user uninstall org.flatpaklinux.Suphead
```

However, after uninstall, I still see many files on the system associated with the application, files at all of the following sorts of directories:

```
~/.local/share/flatpak/repo/refs/remotes/org.flatpaklinux.Suphead-origin
~/.local/share/flatpak-linux/Suphead
~/.local/share/flatpak-linux/Suphead/drive_c
~/.var/app/org.flatpaklinux.Suphead
```

Should Flatpak not remove directories like these and their contents? Should I just do an `rm -rf` on them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's usual for package management tools to leave files in the home directory alone, so that user preferences, etc. are retained on reinstallation. You can choose to delete them if you wish, but I wouldn't expect `flatpak` (or any other software installation tool) to delete configuration files in my home directory. And that's what `~/.var/app` is, looking at [the example in the flatpak wiki](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Filesystem):

```
.var/
└── app
    └── org.gnome.GEdit
        ├── data
        ├── config
        └── cache
```

`~/.local/share/flatpak/repo/refs/remotes/org.flatpaklinux.Suphead-origin` looks like it's part of flatpak's state, and it could be using it to track it what it had installed and where from (such data is also often kept around after package removal, and anyway they don't occupy much space). From the flatpak wiki:

> Flatpak uses OSTree to distribute and manage applications and
>   runtimes. The repo/ in the above tree is the local OSTree repository.
>   Flatpak creates the active/ directories of applications and runtimes
>   as symlinks to OSTree checkouts (in the same directory). Using OSTree
>   has the advantage that the checkouts are automatically deduped and
>   share diskspace, since OSTree is using hardlinks and content-based
>   addressing. OSTree also makes it easy to roll back to an earlier
>   version, should the need arise.

`refs/remotes/org.flatpaklinux.Suphead-origin` looks very like something from a Git repo:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
73dad27c1c047c159f0ee22d6627af5bfdf4dbfc
```

If that is indeed the case, then that file just indicates which commit of the remote source was at the last time you fetched something from there.

If you think flatpak is taking up too much space even after removing an app, check the output of `flatpak list -d --app --runtime` to see what apps and runtimes are still installed and the space they take.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution there, and for the detailed description of how Flatpak stores things.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [here](https://twitter.com/FlatpakApps/status/1543100080126771200),

```sh
flatpak uninstall --delete-data  # Delete app data
```

will remove already uninstalled app data still left on `~/.var/app`.

By default will ask for each app, `Delete data for Application_ID? [y/n]:`.

**With GUI**: *[Warehouse](https://github.com/flattool/warehouse) is a versatile toolbox for managing flatpak user data, viewing flatpak app info, and batch managing installed flatpaks.*

Answer (score -2):

You can uninstall these by using the `--unsed` modifier.

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Ref:
http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html?highlight=uninstall#flatpak-uninstall

Comment: this is to remove unused apps not for the files remaining after uninstalling an app