# How to properly uninstall flatpak

Tags: command-line, uninstall, flatpak

I've uninstall `flatpak` with:

```bsh
sudo apt remove flatpak
```

but I'm getting a:

```
flatpak: command not found
```

everytime I start the terminal, I checked the `.profile` and the `.bashrc` to see where that command could be invoked but found nothing. I even used fzf to search and remove any flatpak things left behind and checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969920/how-should-the-files-of-a-flatpak-application-be-removed) and remove the relevant files but I'm still getting that error when lunching the terminal. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems this file in:

```bsh
/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh
```

was causing the issues. After deleting everything worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed in previous answer, the problem comes from `/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh` file.

To avoid removing it by hand (I don't like this on system files) you can use `apt`:

```
sudo apt purge flatpak
```